# How do I make git credential-osxkeychain work correctly when I'm connected to a machine via SSH?

Tags: terminal, ssh, keychain, remote-desktop, git

I setup a build machine to check out sources from Github by caching the login credential in the keychain using instructions from: https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/

Using `SSH` to connect to the build machine and run the instructions provided fails silently, asking me for a password for each `git clone` command.

Using `VNC` to connect to the build machine and run the instructions provided prompts me the first time, as expected, but not for any subsequent `git clone` commands, and successfully adds the credential to the keychain.

How can I configure the credential helper and/or keychain to make this work over `SSH` without a `VNC` connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ForwardAgent` option in `~/.ssh/config`, if it is allowed on server by option `AllowAgentForwarding` (in `sshd_config`).

Or just simply with a switch `-A` to `ssh`. It will forward connection to your agent to the server and you will be able to authenticate to github.